# linux command convert to java equivalent so as to use as an API

Tags: java, linux

What is the equivalent of below to **jsp** , below i am posting request to the **http url** , want to write the same using java

```
 curl -k --request POST --header "Content-type: text/xml" --data @login.xml http://IP/lcmw
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://IP/lcmw");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
con.setDoOutput(true);
try(FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("login.xml")) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[1000];
    int bytes = 0;
    while( (bytes = fs.read(buf)) > 0) {
        con.getOutputStream().write(buf,0,bytes);
    }
}
con.getOutputStream().flush();
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("responseCode = " + responseCode);
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
    br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```